# Change react class state between DOM elements

Tags: reactjs, class, dom, state, element

I have 2 react DOM elements navbar and content-box. When clicked on an item in navbar, I would like it to change the state of content-box class component, thus, display another content.

```
class Content extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        content: "news"
    }
}}

class Navbar extends Component{

render() {
    <button onClick={change state of Content element to "sport"} />
}}
```

Also, if a have multiple elements in DOM that I would like to be called independently is this the correct way?

In index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Navbar />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('navbar')
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Content />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

these are then in the index.html called in different places.

Comment: Should have mentioned that I am a beginner to React, so I am not completely sure about the structure of DOM elements and their placements on a page. If I got it wrong, do you please any resources where the structure is summed up in one place?

Comment: You shouldn't and don't need to use multiple `render`s like that. Render only one thing in your app, then create your app logic by using components. What you want there is passing a state to a child component. You can use a parent component, keep your state there, and pass it to the child. But, if the Navbar and other components are not going to be parent and children, then you should use either Context or a global state manager. Create your project with Create React App, and don't play with `index.js`. Just create other components and use them in your `App.js`.

Comment: By the way, as a learner try to stay away from a complex state structure, hence Context and a global state manager. You don't need those right now. You should go through the official documentation. Also, I suggest starting with hooks API.

Comment: @devserkan Thanks for your reply. I have restructured the project and it works as I expected. Thank you